# REST WCF not supporting List<int>

Tags: json, vb.net, angularjs, wcf, rest

This is very strange, i'm trying to post JSON data to my WCF service.

```
<OperationContract>
<WebInvoke(Method:="POST", RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)>
Function getProvinciasByAsignacion(asignaciones As List(Of String)) As List(Of String)
```

It works perfectly fine. But... the strange thing here, is if i change string list to integer list, the wcf service returns 400 (bad request).

This is the JSON code that i send (through angular)

```
{"asignaciones":[290,291]}
```

Is this a bug? or a limitation? I'm very lost here! Hope someone could help me...

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. When I enabled includeExceptionDetailInFaults in my web.config I was able to see that my function was doing an invalid cast in the return statement.

If I just do that first instead of asking... what a shame.

Bye!